# Can't find the bug in my code

Tags: actionscript-3

The code is:

```
 var _bgin:Date = new Date();
    var _end:Date   = new Date();
    function sineWaveGenerator(b_arr:ByteArray,p:int, w:uint = 1):void {
        _bgin = _end;
        _end = new Date();
        var st:uint =  
            _end.valueOf() - 
            _bgin.valueOf(); // line 179
    }
```

The error message:

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
>   object reference.     at
>   stopAllExample_fla::MainTimeline/sineWaveGenerator()[stopAllExample_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:179]

I call the function from an event handler. The error appears only once and no error in the all following funcion calls.

Comment: Which is line 179?

Comment: I marked it in the code comment. Is there any possibility, that Flash counts lines incorrectly?

Comment: I know nothing of ActionScript, but there seems to be a scope problem such that inside the function `_end` is treated as a new local variable. Pass `_end` as a parameter instead, perhaps?

Comment: No, it used global variables. Otherwise, it wouldn't work at all, but it works

Comment: Trace **_bgin** and **_end** before the line producing the error. Somehow error shows that **_end** is **null** at the moment you call the function.

Comment: Seems, that the function called **before** global variable _bgin is instantiated. Hm... What to do?

Answer (score 1):

I had to move the initial definitions of the globals up